# PHP - How to avoid infinite loop in Redirect by htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to redirect my visitors to a specific virtual url according the country they are. For example, if you are in Usa and enter www.mysite.com/subsite, you are redirect to www.mysite.com/subsite/US/
If you enter www.mysite.com/subsite/contact.php you have to be redirect to www.mysite.com/subsite/US/contact.php. Same for another country, for ex, Argentina (AR), you will be redirect to www.mysite.com/subsite/AR/contact.php . In the back, you will always see the physical content of www.mysite.com/subsite/contact.php.

I was reading a lot about this and try to do it by editing htaccess, and it works (sort of...) but I got an infinite loop. I try to make a rule that says "if you don't have the string 'AR' in your url, make the redirect, otherwise, stay as you come", but it isn't working. Could anyone please help me. Here's my code so far:

```
GeoIPEnable On

RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!.*AR).*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^AR$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/AR/$1 [R]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this line:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!.*AR).*$ [NC]
```

The variable `%{HTTP_HOST}` is the domain name requested by the browser. To check the path, you would use `%{REQUEST_URI}`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!.*/AR(?:$|/)) [NC]
```